# FOSCommentBundle Sorting

Tags: symfony, foscommentbundle

How do I configure Ascending sorting on the FOSCommentBundle

I've tried the following,  but I keep getting a "Maximum function nesting level"(which is set at 200) error.

```
fos_comment:
  service:
    sorting:
      default: (ASC sorting service)
```

Any ideas? Is there any actual documentation on how to properly configure this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is the correct config to do this. The error was actually because I needed to set my xdebug nesting level even higher.

Checkout @stof's response here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/issues/436

Similarly, the documentation I created for how to configure this got merged in: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/14-customizing_tree_sorting.md